# How to dynamically execute a method on an element that may or may not be an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some sort of approach like,

```
import { isEqual, isArray } from 'lodash';

const valuesEqual = (val1, val2) =>
  isEqual(
    a[isArray(a) ? 'sort' : null](),
    c[isArray(b) ? 'sort' : null]()
  )

let a = [1,2]
let b = [2,1]
console.log(valuesEqual(a, b))
a = '1'
b = '1'
console.log(valuesEqual(a, b))
```

Is something like this possible?

I\m trying to avoid something like,

```
const initIsArray = isArray(a);
if (initIsArray) {
  if (isEqual(a.sort(),b.sort())) {
    // ...
  }
}
else if (a === b) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you're overcomplicating it `if(isArray(a)) a.sort()` and you're done. You don't need to make the decision what method to call *as* you're calling the method.

Comment: You're calling the variables by their names from outside the function scope

Comment: I'd use a ternary operator: `isArray(foo) ? foo.sort() : foo`